# How can i get the size of a single mongodb document with the c# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, size, document

Im trying to build an application with c# that first saves a document to mongodb and then checks the size of the document. I have found ways to check the size using the mongodb shell but i can't seem to find the same functionality with the c# driver. I thought i could do it by creating a commanddocument that contained a BsonObject.size() but i couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with C# but each driver have methods to execute pure request to MongoDB even without using driver APIs. just use it.

Answer (score 3):

Running the C# equivalent of db.coll.stats() (as yaoxing suggested) would among other things return the size of the collection, and the average document size, but not actual size of one specific document.

Quoting Robert Stam from his answer from 
[this Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/NqiS2Hq26S4/HqQ7ppEGnA4J)

> ToBson().Length is the only way to get the length of a BsonDocument.(where by length we mean the number of bytes that the BsonDocument requires when converted to a binary BSON stream). You could write a function that calculated the length of a BsonDocument, but it would have to do almost as much work as ToBson anyway.
>   But the easiest is to just use ToBson().Length

Example:

```
BsonDocument doc = coll.FindOne(Query.EQ("_id", ObjectId.Parse("DOC _id HERE")));
int bytesSize = document.ToBson().Length;
```

Answer (score 2):

**MongoDB Shell:**

In the MongoDB shell, you would want to return the `BsonSize` of the document:

```
Object.bsonsize(db.test.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") }))
```

This returns the size of the BSON object (in bytes).

Note that the effective amount of space the document occupies in the database file itself (on disk) will be larger than the size of your document because of [Record Padding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/record-padding/).

This is why there is a difference between the outputs of the `db.test.stats()` and `Object.bsonsize(...)`.

**C#:**

To get the size in your C# app, simply cast the document to BSON and get it's Length:

```
var oid = new BsonObjectId(new ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
var document = database.getCollection("myCollection").findOne(Query.EQ("_id", oid));
var sizeInBytes = document.ToBson().Length
```

Answer (score 1):

if you had a look at the stat function in mongo shell:

```
db.coll.stat  // <--no brackets here
```

It'll show you what's inside:

```
function ( scale ){
    return this._db.runCommand( { collstats : this._shortName , scale : scale } );
}
```

From which you can see it's just running a db command. Thus if you use the corresponding C# API [RunCommand](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.3.1/html/4fe0d8b2-161e-ff83-355d-7517b251d81a.htm), I guess there will not be too many trouble getting what you want.